# Validation not ocurring for custom field type in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to make a custom type in Django:

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class MinOneHundredDecimalField(DecimalField):
    @cached_property
    def validators(self):
        return super().validators + [
            validators.MinValueValidator(100, "Minimum value is 100"),
        ]
```

And I use this in my model:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    amount = MinOneHundredDecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=6,
    )
```

However when testing, I'm able to set amount to a value less than 100:

```
def test_min_val(self):
    my_model = MyModel(amount=50)
    my_model.save()
    self.assertNotEqual(my_model.amount, 50, "Message here")
```

I also tried adding the validator directly in the model, but I get the same result:

```
amount = MinOneHundredDecimalField(
    decimal_places=2,
    max_digits=6,
    validators=[MinValueValidator(100.0, "Minimum value is 0")]
)
```

Any ideas why this validator isn't working? Ty!

Comment: `amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(),decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])`  Why this code not use  in form ??

Comment: Are you need use custom field ??

Comment: I have several fields that I want to add this validation, so I thought just creating a new field type was cleaner. Also, I'm using this via an API so no forms are involved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [**`full_clean()`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method too... So, you have to change the test cases to something like,

```
from django.core import exceptions

class FooTest(TestCase):
    def test_min_val(self):
        my_model = MyModel(amount=50)

        with self.assertRaises(exceptions.ValidationError) as context:
            my_model.full_clean()

        self.assertIn('Minimum value is 100', context.exception.message_dict['amount'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [documentation on validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/), it states

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model

In the section on [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) it says there are three steps involved in validating a model and they are performed when you call a model’s `full_clean()` method.

At the moment you are only calling `save()` which will not trigger the field validation.

You can override the `save()` method in your model to call `full_clean()` but be careful doing this if you later use your model linked to a model form, when validation will be performed automatically.